# Create a matrix of region from position matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix as like as bellow:

```
position    case    control   
1            2        1      
2            4        10
3            1        7
6            12       3
8            5        5 
9            22       9
10           1        24
11           12       2
```

and I want to determine region (every side with different position value equal one) and create a matrix as bellow:

```
region    start    end    min_case     max_case   mean_case    min_control   
1         1        3      1            4          2.33         1      
2         6        6      12           12         12           3
3         8        11     1            22         10           2
```

min_case is the minimum of the position that find in the region and max_case, mean_case, and min_control are as similar. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.

```
library(tidyverse)
new_df <- df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(
    jump = position - c(-1, position[-length(position)]),
    region = cumsum(jump != 1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarize(
    start = min(position),
    end = max(position),
    min_case = min(`#case`),
    max_case = max(`#case`),
    mean_case = mean(`#case`),
    min_control = min(`#control`)
  )
```

If you are not familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), it's just a way to run a series of operations on an element (e.g. the dataframe) without nesting or a bunch of temporary variables.  It takes the result of each operation and plugs it into the first entry of the next.  So the result of the `as.data.frame` function will be the first element of the `mutate` function.

(Note - I can't test this without a reproducible example, and I didn't code all this in, so if it gives an error, post the code to generate the data and I can probably fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `diff` to find consecutive sequence in `position` in order to create group. `dplyr::summarise_all` can be used to get `min/max/mean` for all columns before selecting the ones needed.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(region = cumsum(c(1,diff(position))!=1)+1) %>%
  summarise_all(c("min", "max","mean")) %>%
  select(region, start = position_min, end = position_max, 
         min_case = case_min,  max_case = case_max, 
         mean_case = case_mean,  min_control = control_min) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   region start end min_case max_case mean_case min_control
# 1      1     1   3        1        4       2.3           1
# 2      2     6   6       12       12      12.0           3
# 3      3     8  11        1       22      10.0           2
```